# Read image content via function if the location of image is given as input

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Is it possible to read the image content if the image name is given to a funtion..
Eg: Image name is `img1.jpg`

my function is

```
$scope.readimg = function(img1.jpg){
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this???

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I get the image name from csv file. I need to save the image as long blob data in db.. so what can I do?

Comment: o. its my mistake.. How can i get image content? @keziah

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/934925/6320435

Comment: i HAVE used base64_encode to encode the image. But it is truncated the string. Wt is the pblm.?